# Chart or XY Plotter in C# with .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core

Is it possible to display an XY chart or plot in WinForms running on .NET Core 3.1? If so, how.
Are there .dll's I can download and reference?
The "charts" feature in the toolbox is greyed out. even after I right click on Toolbox > Choose Items > select Charts.

I downloaded ScottPlots and attemped to use it.
Cant select "charts" in the toolbox, it is greyed out.

Comment: The standard charting library is not supported in .NET Core. You can target .NET Framework 4.8 instead. You shouldn't be targeting .NET Core 3.1 in this platform anyway. If you need to move to .NET, target at least .NET 6+. In this case, you need third party libraries, built for .NET (not .NET Framework). For example, [LiveCharts2](https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/LiveCharts2)